# Bootstrap menu affix shrinking upon scroll with brand image - mobile behavior

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Borrowing from a number of examples I created a bootstrap navbar that is affixed to the top of the page, upon scrolling the navbar plus logo image shrink from 100 px to 50 px in height, working perfectly on a desktop pc, normal width browser.

With a smaller mobile device less than 767px I set the parameter to enable the hamburger menu and simple bootstrap dropdown menu.

With the browser very narrow or on a small device if you first access the page and are at the very top you click on the hamburger icon and the menu appears at about 50 px which is in the middle of the height of the logo (100px tall). Within a fraction of a second it jumps to under the logo at 100px where it should. It is this awkward short-lived behavior that I wish to eliminate. It also happens when you collapse the menu. Otherwise it works as planned.

My javascript:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('img').addClass('shrink');
    $('nav').addClass('shrink');
  } else {
    $('img').removeClass('shrink');
    $('nav').removeClass('shrink');
  }
});
```

The relevant CSS:

```
body {
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.navbar {
  min-height: 101px; /* to get the 100px tall image contained within navbar */
}

.navbar.shrink {
  min-height: 51px;
  background: white;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

img {
  max-height: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

img.shrink {
  max-height: 50px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

/* adjust top position of menu on small device due to larger logo */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .collapse { margin-top: 50px; }
  nav.navbar.shrink .collapse {
    margin-top: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
  }
}
```

See demo:

http://www.dottedi.biz/demo/code/public/navbars/shrinking-navbar+logo-scroll.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are targeting wrong selector here

instead

```
.collapse { 
  margin-top: 50px; 
}
```

in your media query, apply

```
.navbar:not(.shrink) .navbar-collapse {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

and this will work for you

see attached img https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAVQr.jpg

Comment: I spent a lot of time trying to figure this out, dabbling around the code, etc., a lot of time. I had never seen before the :not syntax. Yes that fixed the problem.

Comment: there are many things css can do you just have to figured it out how, so start learning